# Voice recognition to identify users using microsoft kinect SDK.

Tags: c#-4.0, kinect, kinect-sdk

I was wondering if there's a way (through the kinect SDK or otherwise) to be able to identify the voice of a person speaking to kinect.  I already know how to use speech recognition commands via the SDK, but I was wondering if I can recognize the voice of the person so in code I'd know who's controlling the kinect. I need something to back up my application if facial recognition doesn't perform right.

Answer (score 0):

The Kinect SDK does not do anything for speech recognition.  The SDK provides a hook to the microphone array, which is all the Kinect is for audio -- a microphone.  All speech recognition events are handled by other applications or SDKs, such as the [Microsoft Speech Platform](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27226).

If you wish to identify someone based on their voice, you will need to either:

1. Pay for a 3rd party application that accepts speech samples and returns a best guess identification when spoken to.
2. Write your own.

Either way, you're talking a lot of money (be it out of pocket, or time).